# Create Unique string in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to create a unique string in robot framework each time I run my script.

```
*** Settings***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  String

*** Variables ***
${RANUSER}  Generate Random String  10  [LETTERS]

*** Test Cases ***
Enter Random Username
   Input Text  //input[@id='userInput']  ${RANUSER}
```

Using this, I always get `Generate Random String  10  [LETTERS]` as my output but I want unique output all the time. Can anyone please help me.

TY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Generate Random String` is a keyword. So you need to call it as a keyword. E.g. like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Enter Random Username
   ${RANUSER}    Generate Random String    10    [LETTERS]
   Input Text    //input[@id='userInput']    ${RANUSER}
```

Or by the custom keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
Create Random User
    ${RANUSER}    Generate Random String    10    [LETTERS]
    [Return]    ${RANUSER}
```

Comment: Generate Random String is a provided keyword and it is in the String library.  http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String will provide you the details.
It recognizes the 4 markers: [LOWER]: Lowercase ASCII characters from a to z.  [UPPER]: Uppercase ASCII characters from A to Z. [LETTERS]: Lowercase and uppercase ASCII characters and [NUMBERS]: Numbers from 0 to 9.